# iptables conn_limit whether to use mangle or filter?

Tags: iptables

OS : CentOS,

WS : apache 2.2

Intention here is to restrict a specific external source ip to have 20 connections per minute , rest all needs to be either drop'ed or Reject'ed

Without specifying the minute, we tried

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --src 1x5.81.18.12 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

While checking netstat -anp |grep 1x5.81.18.12 |wc -l , still i can see 50+ TIME_WAIT, 30+ Est,

can any one of you guide me?